# Eclipse - Run last operation feature

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-neon

I had been searching to download a version of eclipse just because a feature. I have installed it on my machine probably two years ago. Now I wanted to have the same version of the eclipse in my new laptop. But I could not find the feature in any of the versions of eclipse that I am looking for. 
[image]

this feature lets me to run the last operation with a single click. This really helps me during debugging the code. Eclipse version is: [image]

Can any one help if I can get this feature in any version of eclipse? 
thanks in advance

Comment: You mean [this](https://help.eclipse.org/neon/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fviews%2Fdebug%2Fref-relaunch.htm)?

Comment: That's moved to the debug view run entry context menu.... curiously I can't find a way to put it on the tool bar in Eclipse Photon.  But it IS still available.

Comment: Does it terminate and relaunch the last run/debug configuration? Since you can _Shift_ + click the _Run_ and _Debug_ button for that, no extra button is required anymore.